# What is alfUIplugin.plugin?

Tags: macos

I'm cleaning old 3rd-party stuff out of my /System/* subdirectories on 10.11. And I noticed in /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/ the following file: **alfUIplugin.plugin**. The file size is *zero bytes!* And the date modified is in 2012, three years ago; surely it's not part of El Capitan. Right?

I can safely delete this...right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple Support :

> I was chasing this down myself. It looks like this
>   plugin is used for ALF - Application Level Firewall. ... like the
>   System Preferences/security setting/firewall possibly.

_

> I too am seeing those errors after updating to Mavericks on my MacBook
>   Pro.  And, I cannot find any info on what alfUIplugin.plugin is
>   either.  However, upon going to /System/Library/UserEventPlugins
>   folder, I noticed that the plugin file is 0KB.  On my Mac Pro, which
>   is still running Mountain Lion, it is 20KB and on Snow Leopard it's
>   like 50KB.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5505336

Comment: I guess if it's zero bytes, it can't possibly be doing any harm... weird.

Comment: And if it's zero bytes, why do you absolutely want to delete it ? ^^

Comment: How can you delete something that does not exist? That's what I don't understand. Zero bytes would indicate that there are literally no sectors on disk occupied by the file. So how does the file system even know that it's there? I am reminded of the old radio plays, [The Shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shadow).

Comment: In fact, the file name is stored by the file system ;)

Comment: Yet another thing I hate about operating systems. Files should be self contained.